# Websocket and Java Swing front end

Tags: swing, websocket

Is it doable to make Websocket interfaced  with Java Swing front end?  If so how?

Comment: Is the Swing app the client or server? It sounds like the server from your question. Some more information would be useful.

Comment: Oh, it's the client, swing client.

Answer (score 3):

Try mine:

http://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Contains a Client and Server implementation. In the `example` folder there's a simple `JFrame` subclass called `ChatClient`. Look at it's source for a Swing reference.

Essentially you just need to subclass `net.tootallnate.websocket.WebSocketClient` and implement the `onOpen`, `onClose`, and `onMessage` methods. The class has an interface very similarly to the WebSockets API for HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Kaazing WebSocket Gateway ships with support for JavaScript, Flex, Silverlight, but also native Java clients (stand alone as well as applets). For more information, check out
http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/index.html