# Implementing WebSocket in Java Swing Application

Tags: java, websocket, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I created a small java swing application and I want to use WebSocket for the transferring of data from the server to the client. Can someone give me a step by step instructions on how to do it? I'm using **JBoss application server**.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982530/websocket-and-java-swing-front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Approach is to use Jetty WebSocket Client API, Hopping that you already implemented Server Side Web Socket

[Tutorial](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html)

**Maven Dependency**
       
          org.eclipse.jetty.websocket
           websocket-client
           ${project.version}

```
  package examples;

 import java.net.URI;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
 import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;

 public class SimpleEchoClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String destUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
    if (args.length > 0) {
        destUri = args[0];
    }
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
    SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();
    try {
        client.start();
        URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
        System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n", echoUri);
        socket.awaitClose(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, where is the SimpleEchoSocket class? Can you show it?